# Why doesn't show the background image in the body from my website?

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller

A folder **Images** of my website contains HoezenCollageLight.jpg. It worked fine. But now it isn't shown anymore. I still find the image in the folder **Images**.

In the past:

[image]

... and now:

[image]

What could be wrong?

Some code in Site.Master:

```
<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", ...
```

Some code in Site.css:

```
body
{
    background: #cccccc url('../../Images/HoezenCollageLight.jpg') repeat 100% 100%;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969;
}

.page
{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Where is `Site.css` located? It's probably that you have too few or too many `../` in the `url()`.

Comment: It is not changed. Site.css is placed in folder Content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing one of the `../` from the `url()` path should have it find the image.

```
url('../Images/HoezenCollageLight.jpg')
```

Using `../` navigates from the directory containing the stylesheet (`/Content/`) to its parent (`/`), bringing you to the root of your site where the `Images` directory resides.

A 2nd `../` attempts to navigate up from the root directory, which doesn't have a parent (or navigates outside of the virtual directory, if you're using one).

Comment: I think I have added "../". Thanks. But it is strange it works in the localhost area.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code below for body:

```
 background: url('../../Images/HoezenCollageLight.jpg') repeat 100% 100% #cccccc ;
```

instead of

```
 background: #cccccc url('../../Images/HoezenCollageLight.jpg') repeat 100% 100%;
```

This works at certain times.

Comment: It doesn't work. On localhost everything works fine.

Comment: @user1531040 Is this done in IIS? Some times the URL's you have coded in the VS environment aren't the same as in the IIS environment.

Comment: No with FIleZilla (ftp). And developed in VS2012/HTML5. In the past it was VS2010.

Comment: @user1531040 okay, same deal. Make sure the `Images` directory is actually 2 levels higher from your `Site.css` file in FileZilla.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan mentioned, check location of

1. your Site.css
2. your actual background image

in relation to the content file.